# How to donate to most likely minor party congressional candidate in the US?

Tags: united-states, congress, parties, fundraising

I would like to see non-major-party candidates elected to congress.  I don't care which state, and I don't much care what their platform is.

Are there any political organizations whose mission is to simply get independents and/or third parties elected in the US?

Comment: What about an independent who is more likely to vote one party or the other due to similar alignment of beliefs? Any liberal non-Democrat is still going to vote with the Democrats most of the time, and the reverse is true of a conservative non-Republican.

Comment: This is fine.  My primary motivation is to prevent obstructionism and widen political discourse by preventing outright majorities.  Viz. If neither Republicans nor Democrats can count on being able to pass or defeat a proposal based strictly on party loyalty considerations, then bills must necessarily have the substance to convince those "across the aisle" or those otherwise voting their conscience.

Comment: So, if an independent is, say, liberal(conservative) and generally votes liberally(conservatively) this is fine.  However, if an independent votes to simply obstruct party X because they are opposed to the party, and not the bill, then this is not constructive from this angle.  Thus the "due to political ties" limitation.

Comment: @DavidRice, I'm not sure if such independents exist, and thus making such a distinction may cause more confusion than clarification.  What do you think?

Comment: I think that you're ignoring that most politicians are people who have real opinions and they join parties which already align with those opinions in order for them to be more effective at pursuing those opinions. They don't vote that way due to political ties, they have those political ties because of the way they vote.

Comment: "are people who have real opinions and they join parties which already align with those opinions" I concede this point.  However, I find it difficult to believe that in our vast and varied country there is so little difference of opinion that the scope of national values are perfectly captured in the official platforms of the two tightly-knit and bitterly opposed parties that form nearly the entirety of our legislature.  This, and the low rate at which legislators deviate from the party line causes me to suspect that "political ties" are an important dictate of the actions of legislators.

Comment: What rate of deviation from a party would you expect indicates "true" independence?  If someone is on the left, how often should their vote be the same as a majority of republicans?  (I'll see if I can get some data on this)

Comment: @DavidRice, I am not sure.  However, your line of reasoning causes me to think that the limitation above is, indeed, more confusing than clarifying, and I will edit it out.  Thank you for the lively debate.  :)

Comment: I think that if an independent had close political ties with a particular party and intended to simply "toe the party line", they would certainly avail themselves of the massive political benefits that attend association with a major party.

Comment: "I don't much care what their platform is" - Cthulhu for President!!!

Comment: @user4012 Ph'nglui mglw'nafh Cthulhu R'lyeh wgah'nagl fhtagn.

Answer (score 2):

You can check out Unite America at [Unite America](https://www.uniteamerica.org/about)

According to their page

> Unite America is the only organization in the country building the grassroots community, donor network, and electoral infrastructure to help independent candidates run winning campaigns.

Comment: Despite the frequency at which the phenomenon occurs, I am always shocked and amazed when I have an idea for a thing, and someone somewhere is doing that exact thing.  It seems as though the world is big enough to provide me with a never ceasing supply of wonderment.  :)

Comment: Upon reading their website, Unite America does not seem to support third party candidates.  They strictly support independents.  I wonder what the motivation there is?

Comment: @Scott It looks like they believe that a candidate in a party will be looking out for *the party's* interests over the people's, regardless of party. Which makes some sense, given party support and fundraising.